# Link for new template for register

Tags: shopify

I am trying to create a second registration form (with slightly different fields). I have copied the template of customer/register.liquid (say customer/register.xyx.liquid). What will be the URL to access this new page? i.e. what should be the link instead of the original link /account/register?

Comment: try `/account/register?view=xyz`

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much. If you could add that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any new template can be accessed front end by using "?view=" in the webpage URL

For your case try `/account/register?view=xyz`